# Bug? 'nice time' disables $PATH search

Tags: bash, path

With ~/bin at the beginning of my $PATH, I still have to name the directory if I put 'nice time' in front of the filename.  Also, 'which' doesn't find it yet it still runs if I invoke it without 'nice time bin/'.  This was not the case at some time in the recent past.  Is it a bug introduced recently, or a "feature" that Apple failed to support until recently?

```
MBP:~ user$ nice time copy_websites
copy_websites: No such file or directory
        0.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
MBP:~ user$ echo $PATH
~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin
MBP:~ user$ which copy_websites
MBP:~ user$ which bash
/bin/bash
MBP:~ user$ head -1 bin/copy_websites 
#!/bin/bash
MBP:~ user$ ls -lat@e bin/co*
-rwx------@ 1 user  staff  747 Mar 10 13:36 bin/copy_websites
    com.apple.TextEncoding   15 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_zla7g6mgqwkmgzlaez4j64ql5q   89
```

Comment: What does `type copy_websites` say? Does it help if you replace the `~` in `PATH` with the expanded home folder?

Comment: You have the tilde (~) quoted in your  PATH variable assignment. You can use $HOME instead, inside the quoted assignment.

Comment: ? I don't see any quote marks there.  Is your meaning that ~ is not expanded in $PATH?  Why did the behavior change?

Comment: Where and how exactly did you add `~/bin` to the `PATH`? If, e.g., I add `export PATH=~/bin:$PATH` to my `~/.profile` file, it properly expands it to `/Users/me/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin`. (I choose to use `~/.profile` however you can use `~/.bash_profile` or, `~/.bash_login`.) What version of OS X/macOS are you running?

Comment: It is added in .bashrc which has not changed in months, probably more than a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the handling of `~` differs between the shell and the macOS kernel. If you run your command directly from the prompt, `PATH` expansion is handled by the shell which knows how to expand `~`. If you run your command through `nice`, the command is passed to the macOS kernel for path expansion:

```
pse@Mithos:~$ mkdir foo
pse@Mithos:~$ cat >foo/foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo foo here
pse@Mithos:~$ chmod +x foo/foo.sh
pse@Mithos:~$ foo/foo.sh
foo here
pse@Mithos:~$ PATH='~/foo':$PATH
pse@Mithos:~$ echo $PATH
~/foo:/Users/pse/.bin/script:/Users/pse/.bin/i386:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
pse@Mithos:~$ foo.sh
foo here
pse@Mithos:~$ time foo.sh
foo here

real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.002s
pse@Mithos:~$ nice time foo.sh
foo.sh: No such file or directory
        0.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
pse@Mithos:~$ nice foo.sh
nice: foo.sh: No such file or directory
pse@Mithos:~$
```

**To avoid this, always make sure that your *assigned* PATH contains neither `~` nor any nonexpanded variables.**

PS: Additionally there are different `time` commands called for `time foo` and `nice time foo`.  To get the same output format in both cases, use `/usr/bin/time foo` instead.

Comment: So $HOME won't work as someone else said?

Comment: @WGroleau, If you use single or double quotes around `~`, like matrix did `PATH='~/foo':$PATH`, it **will not** be expanded regardless of where or how you use it! In the default OS X/macOS _shell_, which is `bash` using an unquoted form of `~` will be expanded by the `bash` _shell_ before being passed to the executable on the command line. If placed in e.g. `~/.profile`, e.g.`export PATH=~/bin:$PATH` it's expanded as the `bash` shell opens. That said, I personally try to avoid using `~` and opt for either `$HOME` or `/Users/me` just to avoid any issue that might occur.

Comment: @patrix, Your _command_, `PATH='~/foo':$PATH` is not the correct way to add `~/anything` to the `PATH` as it **must be passed in an unquoted form to be expanded** in a `bash` _shell_!

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, that's the whole point of my answer. The copy from Terminal is just to demonstrate the effect an unexpanded `~` has within `PATH` (same as the `PATH` shown in the question).

Comment: @patrix, Okay, for a moment I wasn't sure, although from the overall quality of your answers, I should have been though, sorry.